# Casting string into <Integer>ArrayList

Tags: java, string, casting, integer

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers ending with 0.");

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String num = scan.nextLine();

    for(int x=0; x < num.length(); x++){
        System.out.println(num.charAt(x));

        int y = num.charAt(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        list.add(y);
        System.out.println(list);


    }
```

Im trying to cast a string of numbers into a array. Its not adding the correct vaule. I keep getting 49 and 50. I want to store the numbers the user enters into the ArrayList. Can someone help?

Comment: That is because its giving you the ASCII value, `int y = num.charAt(x)-48` or `Character.valueOf(num.charAt(x))` since '0' is represented by 48, refer: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Thilo and my answer will give you expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int y = num.charAt(x);
```

That will give you the Unicode codepoint for the character. Like 65 for A or 48 for 0.

You probablay want

```
 int y = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(x, x+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(num.charAt(x));
```

instead of

```
int y = num.charAt(x);
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt is not applicable for char as a method argument. You code will give compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting the input to Integer, thus JVM  is taking them as string. Assuming you are 1 as you input it is printing 49 (ASCII equivalent) of "1".

If you want to get the integral values, you need to parse it using

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(num.charAt(x));
System.out.println(y);
list.add(y);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt is not applicable for char as a method argument. You code will give compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

As this code `int y = num.charAt(x);` is creating the problem. As you are trying to store returned character into int value, so it is storing ASCII value of the character.

You can go with the suggestions in other answers.

---

For the simplicity, you can rewrite your code like this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers ending with 0.");

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

String num = scan.nextLine();

char[] charArray = num.toCharArray();
for (char c : charArray) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        int y = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        System.out.println(y);
        list.add(y);
        System.out.println(list);
    } else {
         // you can throw exception or avoid this value.
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** `Integer.valueOf` and `Integer.parseInt` will not give proper result for char as a method argument. You need to pass String as a method argument in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying a char into an int. You need to convert it into an int value.

```
int y = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(x));
```

Comment: Your method is taking integer as an input ([`Integer valueOf(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)), so in this case it will return ASCII value.

Comment: check this out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String) besides num.charAt(x) does not return an int.

Comment: That is for String, not for char. In your code, it is passing char, so internally it will call valueOf(int i) method, and it will pass ASCII value of char (returned by num.charAt(x)) as a method argument. You can check by executing your code.

Comment: You are right, valueOf method doesn't give the correct value;

Comment: Your code can work like this `int y = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(num.charAt(x)));`. Refer note part of my answer to this question.